# Clojure Ring: How to determine if development server is running?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I have a project containing both Clojure & ClojureScript code. I would like to include unoptimized ClojureScript when I run my server via `lein ring server` and optimized ClojureScript otherwise. What is the idiomatic way to do this?

I am using:

```
[[bidi "1.19.0"]
 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-beta3"]
 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3269"]]

[[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
 [lein-ring "0.9.4"]]
```

My handler is just a simple one:

```
(def app (-> ["/" {:get {"" index-view}}]
             (compile-route)
             (make-handler)))
```

and this is my server directive:

```
:ring {:handler webapp.core/app}
```

I am looking for a way to be able to do this in my views:

```
(dev-server? request) ;; => true if it's a development server, otherwise false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to use [leiningen profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md), using the `:dev` profile. You can then ensure inside the dev profile that your ClojureScript build is happening without optimization, cf. the [leiningen cljsbuild compilation profiles](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/wiki/Compilation-profiles).

If you want to be able to identify the devserver running, you can use [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ) -- include `:env {:dev true}` in your `:dev` profile and then in your code you can just call `(env :dev)`. You might want to take a look at the [reagent-template](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-template) for inspiration.

Comment: My problem is not about building ClojureScript.

Comment: I updated the answer to address your `dev-server?` issue. Take a look at the reagent-template which sets up a somewhat complex cljsbuild where your problem (selecting optimized/unoptimized) is solved.